# What does this mean in regex: \g{last_name}

Tags: regex, perl

So I am going over some examples for Perl regex (I am very new to the world of regular expressions)

And I saw this statement:

```
my $names = 'Fred Flintstone and Wilma Flintstone';

if ( $names =~ m/(?<last_name>\w+) and \w+ \g{last_name}/ ){
    print "I saw $+{last_name}";
}
```

In the if conditional, I know that it is labeling the first capture to be last name, which captures only word characters, but the stuff after the and.

What in detail is going on there?  Is it saying if the word is matched again in a back reference, then print the capture?

Comment: Now [you have two problems](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)?

Comment: yes. if it was `Fred Flintstone and Betty Rubble`, then it wouldn't match, because the last names aren't the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ( $names =~ m/(?<last_name>\w+) and \w+ \g{last_name}/ ){
```

The trick here is realizing that `and` doesn't stand for the boolean operation, but the text `and` that appears in the string `$names`.

Let's make this a wee bit simpler:

```
my $names = 'Fred Flintstone and Wilma Flintstone';
if ( $names =~ /(\w+) and \w+ \1/ ) {
    say "There's a matching last name: $1";
}
```

Here I'm using the more familiar *relative* form of the capture. Let's look at the matching:

- `(\w+)` matches "Flintstone" and creates a capture group.
- `and` matches " and "
- `\w+` matches "Wilma"
- `\1` matches the first capture group `Flintstone`.

  This will print out "There's a matching last name: Flintstone

This:

```
my $names = 'Fred Flintstone and Barney Rubble';
if ( $names =~ /(\w+) and \w+ \1/ ) {
    say "There's a matching last name: $1";
}
```

won't print anything out because "Rubble" doesn't match the `\1` selector.

Answer (score 0):

The `\w` is a character class that is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` (or all letters and digits in all possible alphabets, depending of the context, plus the underscore)

`+` is a quantifier to repeat 1 or more times.

`\g{last_name}` is a backreference to the capture group with the same name, and stand for the content captured with this group.

Comment: `\w` matches for more characters than those. Those are simply the US-ASCII ones it matches